# Find $ \int \frac {\tan 2x} {\sqrt {\cos^6x +\sin^6x}} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> **Problem**: Find  $\displaystyle\int \frac {\tan 2x} {\sqrt {\cos^6 x +\sin^6 x}} dx $
>
> **Solution**: $\tan 2x= \dfrac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$
>
> Also I can take $\cos^6x$ common from $\sqrt {\cos^6x +\sin^6x}$

I don't know whether it is good approach to the question

Please help

Comment: Simplifying the surd in the denominator might help

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown. Some MathJax advice: Named math operators should appear upright, and the common ones have their own code for this purpose (e.g. `\sin`, `\log` - see entry 11 in our MathJax guide).

Comment: @ZevChonoles,thanks,in future I will take care of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\cos^6x+\sin^6x=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^3-3\cos^2x\sin^2x(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)$$
$$=1-3\cos^2x\sin^2x=1-\frac34(\sin2x)^2$$
$$=1-3\cos^2x\sin^2x=1-
\frac34(\sin2x)^2=1-\frac34(1-\cos^22x)=\frac{1+3\cos^22x}4$$

Use $\cos2x=u$

Comment: Thanks,now it is easy to solve

Comment: @rst, my pleasure